# Why do `perl Foo.pm` and `perl -I. -mFoo -e1` behave differently?

Tags: perl, module, warnings, require

With this code in Foo.pm:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
package Foo;

BEGIN {
  $Foo::AUTHORITY = 'cpan:ETHER';
}
1;
```

Loading the file as a module gives no errors:

```
$ perl -I. -mFoo -e1
$
```

And yet, loading the file directly does:

```
$ perl Foo.pm
Name "Foo::AUTHORITY" used only once: possible typo at Foo.pm line 6.
```

Moreover, `perl -e'require "Foo.pm"'` also does not warn.

Why is there this difference? Clearly the file is being parsed differently,
but how and why?

Comment: You do not have to specify `-I.`, the current directory is always included in `@INC`.

Comment: @TLP - not in taint mode

Comment: @mob Ok, *almost* always.

Comment: Yeah, but for taint mode, who have to specify -T on the command line in these cases.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Why" from a technical point of view, or from a language design point of view?

From a language point of view, it makes sense because a variable referred to within a module may well be part of the module's public API. For example, Data::Dumper exposes a bunch of package variables that alter its behaviour. (Arguably bad design, but ho hum.) These variables might only be referred to once in the module, but can potentially be referred to from other parts of the program.

If it's only referred to in the main script once, and no modules refer to it, then it's more likely to be a mistake, so we get this warning within the script, but not in the module.

From a technical point of view, this warning is generated by `gv.c`. Personally I can't make head nor tail of the exact conditions under which it's triggered.

Answer (score 0):

Surely the exception was made because some modules do

```
if ($Me::Setting) {
   ...
} else {
   ...
}
```

We didn't always have `our` and `use vars` (the latter depending on yet an other exception for imported symbols).

---

Warnings are issued with `warn` (Perl side) or `Perl_warner` (C side). The line in question is [this one](http://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git/blob/dd686e5619f8ad9e1e46ec0e80539edbcb73c8ea:/gv.c#l2112).

Comment: I have guesses too, but what I'm interested in is concrete facts. thanks! :)

Comment: @Ether, Yet you accepted an answer that makes the same educated guess I did (public API) while providing none of the corroboration I did (mechanism to declare didn't use to exist)?

Comment: he linked to the source, which confirms that this is intentional behaviour (and shows the "how").

Comment: What are you talking about? He didn't link to the source, and he didn't confirm it's intentional. He didn't even say whether he thought the lack of warning is intentional or not. Quite the opposite, he said he couldn't makes heads or tail of it. He merely pointed out the name of the file containing the code issuing the warning. That doesn't speak to intention of anything! That just shows code to emit the warnings exists, which we already knew.

Comment: Note that it's in the file that contains all the code that deals with package variables. Where else would it be? It doesn't speak to intent at all!